# Python Image classification trouble shooting

Tags: python

Hi guys sorry this might be a dumb question but i've been looking where's this variable came from

```
def predict(file):
```

as you can see on 'predict' there a parameter called 'file'
i was wondering where's does the data on 'file' came from

thank you!

here's the full code

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
import time

start = time.time()

# Define Path
# model_path = './models/model.h5'
# model_weights_path = './models/weights.h5'
test_path = 'data/test_image'

# Load the pre-trained models
# model = load_model(model_path)
# model.load_weights(model_weights_path)

# Define image parameters
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

# Prediction Function


def predict(file):
    model_path = './models/model.h5'
    model_weights_path = './models/weights.h5'
    model = load_model(model_path)
    model.load_weights(model_weights_path)
    x = load_img(file, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
    x = img_to_array(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    array = model.predict(x)
    result = array[0]
    # print(result)
    answer = np.argmax(result)
    if answer == 0:
        print("Predicted: Drusen")
    elif answer == 1:
        print("Predicted: Normal")

    return answer


# Walk the directory for every image
for i, ret in enumerate(os.walk(test_path)):
    for i, filename in enumerate(ret[2]):
        if filename.startswith("."):
            continue

        print(ret[0] + '/' + filename)
        result = predict(ret[0] + '/' + filename)
        print(" ")

# Calculate execution time
end = time.time()
dur = end-start

if dur < 60:
    print("Execution Time:", dur, "seconds")
elif dur > 60 and dur < 3600:
    dur = dur/60
    print("Execution Time:", dur, "minutes")
else:
    dur = dur/(60*60)
    print("Execution Time:", dur, "hours")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call of `predict(file)` is as follows:

```
result = predict(ret[0] + '/' + filename)
```

So it takes as input a filename. Inside the function, this part

```
x = load_img(file, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
```

Uses the `load_img` function, from the `keras.preprocessing.image` module. So the `file` parameter takes a filename, and transforms it into an image there:

```
x = img_to_array(x)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
array = model.predict(x)
```

It's being added a *channel* dimension, after being turned into a `NumPy` array. At the end, its label is predicted.